# Using margins command in R with quadratic term and interacted dummy variables

Tags: r, logistic-regression, marginal-effects

My objective is to create marginal effects and a plot similar to what's done in this post under "marginal effects": https://www.drbanderson.com/myresources/interpretinglogisticregressionpartii/

Since I cannot provide the actual model or actual data (data is sensitive), I will provide a generic example.

I have the following model created using the glm function:

```
model = glm(y ~ as.factor(x1) + x2 + I(x2^2) + x3 + as.factor(x4):as.factor(x5), data = dataFrame,family="binomial")
```

x2 is a continuous variable that I want to calculate marginal effects at the average of the other continuous variable, x3, and at pre-defined values for x1, x4, and x5. For further simplification, assume x1 is categorical of either morning, afternoon, or night (thus producing two coefficients in the logit model), x4 is categorical of either left or right, and x5 is categorical of either up or down (thus x4:x5 produces coefficient results for left and up, left and down, right and up, with right and down the excluded interaction).

Similar to what is done in the post, I run the following code:

```
x2.inc <- seq(min(dataFrame$x2), max(dataFrame$x2), by = .1)
```

to get a sequence of x2 values at which to evaluate the marginal effect. Finally, I attempt to run the margins command:

```
x2.margins.df <- as.data.frame(summary(margins(model, at = list(x2 = x2.inc, x3 = mean(dataFrame$x3), x1 = 'morning', x4 = 'left', x5 = 'right'))))
```

However, running this produced the following error:

```
Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Any thoughts on how I can successfully run the margins command given a) the quadratic nature of x2 in my model, and b) the interaction of terms in the model?

As a side note: I know I can calculate these things manually if I wanted to. However, for the sake of having less code and ease of reproducibility, I'd like to make this method work. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The readme of `margins` says:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/readme/README.html

that it supports `logit` models. So why implement somethiny manually?

```
library("car")
library("plm")
data("LaborSupply", package = "plm")

model <- glm(disab ~ kids*age + kids*I(age^2), data = LaborSupply, family="binomial")
summary(margins(model))
```